# Laravel Eloquent Join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables and I want to join them. I have looked at other examples and just can't figure it out.

My tables are as follows.

- Clubs

  - id
  - name
- Members

  - id
  - club_id
  - name

A club has many members 
 A member belongs to a club

I can list my clubs and after listing my clubs i can list the members of the club ok, but what I want to do is list all my members and show their club. So my output would be ID, Name, Club Name

This is my code setup so far

```
// clubs controller
public function index()
{
    $clubs = Club::all();
    return View::make('clubs.list')->with('clubs', $clubs);
}

public function show($id)
{
    $club = Club::findOrFail($id);
    $members = $club->Members()->get();
    return View:: make('clubs.show')->with('club', $club)->('members', $members);
}

// club model
class Club extends Eloquent
{
    // each club has many members
    public function Members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Member');
    }
}


// members controller
public function index()
{
    $members = Member::all();
    return View::make('members.list')->with('members', $members);
}

// member model
class Member extends Eloquent
{
    // each member belongs to one club
    public function club()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Club');
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `foreach(Member::all() as $member) { echo $member->name . ' belongs to the club ' . $member->club->name; }`?

Comment: ive tried that in both the controller method and on the blade page. Both work but would one be making more queries?

Comment: Right, you're making a query for the club on each iterarion. What you're actually looking for is [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading). `Member::with('club')->get()` would only execute 2 queries (`select * from members` and `select * from clubs where id in (....)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Member` model declare the following relationship method:

```
public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Club');
}
```

So now you can query all members with their `Club` info as:

```
$members = Member::with('club')->get();
```

In your `View` when looping the `Members` you may try something like this:

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    {{ $member->name }}
    {{ $member->club->name }}
@endforeach
```

This is not `Eloquent Join` but using it's relationship technique you may do it as given above, if you want to join then you may try something like this:

```
$members = Member::join('clubs', 'members.club_id', '=', 'clubs.id')
                 ->select('members.*', 'clubs.name as club_name')
                 ->get();
```

In this case, you may loop and use the `Club` info like this;

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    {{ $member->name }}
    {{ $member->club_name }}
@endforeach
```