# How to do a full join in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I perform a full join given two tables t1 and t2 in laravel eloquent?

Comment: It would be helpfull to know your tables structure in order to be able to help you. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Just put the Fulljoin SQL command in `DB::select("your sql code here")`;

Comment: Do you mean an `OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872376/laravel-eloquent-join)

Answer (score 3):

If you were using MySQL.

MySQL has no inbuilt support for full outer join.

But you can use the code like this below to achieve that.

```
$table2 = DB::table('t2')
         ->rightJoin('t1', 't1.id', '=', 't2.t1_id')

$table1 = DB::table('t1')
        ->leftJoin('t2', 't1.id', '=', 't2.t1_id')
        ->unionAll($table1)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of query builder join functions have an optional argument called `$type ='inner'`
so if you database supports full join (e.g: postgres) just pass "full" as the $type parameter