# How to perform outer join in laravel for mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to perform Full outer join on Mysql in Laravel.(I know that Mysql doesn't suppurt Full Outer Join)
I want to select all field of table1 where id=$formId and a field of table2.

```
       DB::table('forms')
            ->leftJoin('answers',function($join) use($formId){
                $join->on('forms.formid', '=' ,'answers.formid')
                ->where('forms.formid',$formId);
            })
            ->select('forms.*','answers.uniqid')
            ->get();
```

but the where condition doesn't work?

Comment: ->join('table2','table1.id', '=' ,'table2.id', 'left outer')

Comment: Please refer to this link you will find the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722604/how-to-do-a-full-join-in-laravel-eloquent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a full join in Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722604/how-to-do-a-full-join-in-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my where place and it solved my issue.

```
      DB::table('forms')
            ->leftJoin('answers',function($join) use($formId){
                $join->on('forms.formid', '=' ,'answers.formid');
            })
            ->where('forms.formid','109')
            ->select('forms.*','answers.uniqid')
            ->get();
```

But Laravel Doc locate where in join function!

```
  DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
             ->where('contacts.user_id', '>', 5);
    })
    ->get();
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)